# Multiple CSV Import Object mapper

Tags: c#, csv

I'm really new to this so appreciate your help...

So I have the challenge of importing a large amount of data into an existing sql 2012 db, from 3 csv files for each new Client of mine, their are 50 new clients, each have 3 csv files.

I'm creating a mini windows forms application, and im importing on an individual client basis.

[image]

However the design concept of how to keep the data relational is what I'm struggling with.

This is the basic csv object mapping:

[image]

So I can read in Client data, but I have no idea how to read in the orders and appointments and maintain the linkage between them all while assigning new Ids ?)

```
private void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtClients.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAccountId.Text))
    {
        var accountId = txtAccountId.Text;

        var clientData = File.ReadAllLines(txtClients.Text)
           .Skip(1)
           .Select(x => x.Split(','))
           .Select(x => new Client()
           {
               ClientTempId = int.Parse(x[0]),
               FirstName = x[1],
               LastName = x[2],
               AccountId = accountId,
               Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
           });

        //Import Orders and then Appointments and maintain relationships....
    }
}

public class Client
{
    public string Id  { get; set; }
    public int ClientTempId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string AccountId { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int OrderTempId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
    public string AccountId { get; set; }
}

public class Appointment
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int AppointmentTempId { get; set; }
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public string AccountId { get; set; }
}
```

I appreciate examples and help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

In such situations I often use the trick of creating a guid from the old int key like this:

```
string guid = String.Format("00000000-0000-0000-0000-{0:000000000000}", id);
```

This yields a guid like:

> 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000077

This enables you to keep the relations between the records easily.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar requirement at my job. What I do is load each file separately (but in proper sequence), each to a temporary staging table. The staging tables do not have any referential constraints, and I do not care about maintaining referential integrity while loading data from the files to the staging tables. After all of the files are loaded, I then use queries to insert/update the master tables, again keeping things in the correct order. The key thing here is to make sure to only insert/update records from the staging tables if their parent FK exists in the parent table, and this can easily be accomplished in one query (per child table) using joins. The data is all on the SQL server at that point, so copying data from one table to the another can be very quick. In the same way it is also possible to report or otherwise take action on any orphaned child records. In the end, I drop the staging tables, and the master tables are all nice and consistent.